# JavaScript Deck Builder: Shuffle, Draw Cards

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for critiques or different ways I could approach writing a deck builder script. I wrote script to shuffle a deck of cards, then draw cards from the top of deck, drawn cards are then removed from deck and placed into discard.

```
const cardGame = {
values: [ 'Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Joker', 'Queen', 'King' ],
suits: [ 'Clubs', 'Spades', 'Hearts', 'Diamonds' ],
deck: [],
discard: [],
buildDeck() {
    const { deck, values, suits } = this;

    //clear deck and discard pile
    deck.splice(0, 52);
    this.discard.splice(0, 52);

    //regenerate/build deck
    for (let suit of suits) {
        for (let value of values) {
            deck.push({ value, suit });
        }
    }
},
shuffle() {
    const { deck } = this;
    for (let i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [ deck[i], deck[j] ] = [ deck[j], deck[i] ];
    }
},
// drawCard(numCards = 1) {
//  const { deck, discard } = this;
//  for (let i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
//      let card = deck[i];
//      deck.splice(i, 1);
//      console.log(card);
//      discard.push(card);
//  }
//  console.log(deck.length);
// },
drawCard(numCards = 1) {
    const { deck, discard } = this;
    const removedCards = deck.splice(0, numCards);

    for (let card of removedCards) {
        console.log(card);
        discard.push(card);
    }
    console.log(deck.length);
},
start() {
    this.buildDeck();
    this.shuffle();
},
shuffleDraw(numCards) {
    this.drawCard(numCards);
    this.shuffle();
};
cardGame.start();
```

I commented out what I thought the ideal way to write the drawCard() method. This was because I could not get it to work. The for loop would skip over every other index, for example:

[image]

I am not sure why this is? I tried searching for an explanation, but struggled to find one. If anyone can explain why this is or refer to a source to explain why it is skipping every other index?
Thank you

Comment: Take this question to StackOverflow and with the code working, bring it back here to Code Review.  Situations like this is why there are separate forums.

Comment: Do not add or remove items from an array while iterating ( `for`, `forEach`, etc. ) said array. Changing the value of an item is ok, but not adding or removing.

Comment: One nice way to draw cards is to map to the unicode range that has cards (take care to skip over "knight") and use html entities (`&#0xABCD;` or whatever the number actually is...).